# PHP get previous array element knowing current array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with specific keys:

```
array(
    420 => array(...), 
    430 => array(...), 
    555 => array(...)
)
```

In my application I know current key (for example `555`). And I want to get the previous array element. In this example it is array element with key `430`. How can I do this in PHP? I tried to work with `prev()`, but for this function we should know current array element. I didn't find function, what set the current array element.

Comment: you can simple iterate over it.

Comment: Are the keys in sorted order?

Comment: As you can see from the explanation below, there is not a single reason to set any pointers in your case. They have another, very limited use.

Comment: @Gumbo. No, keys isn't sorted.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One option:

To [set the internal pointer to a certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795625/how-to-set-an-arrays-internal-pointer-to-a-specific-position-php-xml), you have to forward it (using [`key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [`next`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), maybe do a [`reset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) before to make sure you start from the beginning of the array):

```
while(key($array) !== $key) next($array);
```

**Then** you can use [`prev()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php):

```
$prev_val = prev($array);
// and to get the key
$prev_key = key($array);
```

Depending on what you are going to do with the array afterwards, you might want to [`reset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) the internal pointer.

If the key does not exist in the array, you have an infinite loop, but this could be solved with:

```
 while(key($array) !== null && key($array) !== $key)
```

of course `prev` would not give you the right value anymore but I assume the key you are searching for will be in the array anyway.

Comment: Cool non-foreach solution that actually works with the internal array pointer, +1

Comment: the fact that we would usually go over the array with foreach but he had a different approach that works well and it also uses internal pointers. +1

Comment: So, you just perfectly explained, why these pointers just shouldn't be used. as for `key($array)` - imagine we have a regular enumerated array... ;)

Comment: Shouldn't `key($array)` be `current($array)`

Comment: @RobertPitt: It's either way. `key` will return `null` if the internal pointer points outside of the array and `current` will return `false`. I think `key` is safer to use, because a value might be `false` but it is unlikely that a key will be `null`.

Comment: true, nice method either way.

Comment: @Eduard: Did you get an error? What happened? Did you reset the array before as I mentioned?

Comment: No error, but when accessing the array with the previous key, it threw a notice, that there's no such index in the array. I haven't used any array-specific functions on that array, so I don't think a reset was needed, or is it?

Comment: @Eduard: Are you sure you used the previous key and not the value?

Comment: @FelixKling well I used the previous key, to get the value :)

Answer (score 26):

Solution with fast lookups: (if you have to do this more than once)

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
$values = array_values($array);
return $values[$keys[555]-1];
```

[`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip)`(`[`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys)`($array));` will return an array mapping keys to their position in the original array, e.g. `array(420 => 0, 430 => 1, 555 => 2)`.

And [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values)() returns an array mapping positions to values, e.g. `array(0 => /* value of $array[420] */, ...)`.

So `$values[$keys[555]-1]` effectively returns the previous elements, given that the current one has key 555.

Alternative solution:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
return $array[$keys[array_search(555, $keys)-1]];
```

Answer (score 11):

I solved this issue in this way:

```
function getPrevKey($key, $hash = array()) {
    $keys = array_keys($hash);
    $found_index = array_search($key, $keys);
    if ($found_index === false || $found_index === 0)
        return false;
    return $keys[$found_index-1];
}
```

@return previous key or false if no previous key is available

Example:

```
$myhash = array(
    'foo' => 'foovalue',
    'goo' => 'goovalue',
    'moo' => 'moovalue',
    'zoo' => 'zoovalue'
);

echo "TEST: ". getPrevKey('zoo', $myhash); // prints moo
```

Answer (score 5):

@Luca Borrione's solution was helpful.
If you want to find both previous and next keys, you may use the following function:

```
function getAdjascentKey( $key, $hash = array(), $increment ) {
    $keys = array_keys( $hash );    
    $found_index = array_search( $key, $keys );
    if ( $found_index === false ) {
        return false;
    }
    $newindex = $found_index+$increment;
    // returns false if no result found
    return ($newindex > 0 && $newindex < sizeof($hash)) ? $keys[$newindex] : false;
}
```

Usage:

```
// previous key
getAdjascentKey( $key, $hash, -1 );

// next key
getAdjascentKey( $key, $hash, +1 );
```

Examples:

```
$myhash = array(
    'foo' => 'foovalue',
    'goo' => 'goovalue',
    'moo' => 'moovalue',
    'zoo' => 'zoovalue'
);

getAdjascentKey( 'goo', $myhash, +1 );
// moo

getAdjascentKey( 'zoo', $myhash, +1 );
// false

getAdjascentKey( 'foo', $myhash, -1 );
// false
```

Comment: The comments in the 'Usage' section are misleading. It returns false if the searched key is not found, but will throw an `Undefined offset` notice and return `null` if the result is at the first key and you're looking for the previous. Same for the last key with the next value.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array in reverse and return the next iteration after finding the search value.

```
$found = false;
foreach(array_reverse($array, true) as $key=>$value) {
  if ($found) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
    break;
  } else if ($key == 555) {
    $found = true;
  }
}
```

http://ideone.com/2WqmC

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the array

```
$_index = null;
foreach($myarray as $index => $value)
{
    if($key == $my_index) // if($key == 550)
    {
        break;
    }
    $_index = $index;
}

echo $_index; //the prev key from 550;
```

An alternative solution is to get the keys of your array within an enumerated array like so:

```
$keys = array_keys($my_array);
```

as the keys array is index you can move the the previous key like so:

```
$required_key = (array_search(550,$keys,true) - 1);
```

this will fine the value of `550`, and return its index within the keys, remove one to get the previous index

key we have our previous key to get the value from the original array

```
$value = $my_array[$required_key];
```

Comment: +1 for the `array_keys` approach.  Compact, transparent and easily tweakable.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is large then it might be a best practice to avoid looping. You could make your own custom function, like so:

```
$array = array('first'=>'111', 'second'=>'222', 'third'=>'333');

function previous($key, $array) {
  $keysArray = array_keys($array);
  $keyNumber = array_search($key, $keysArray);
  if ($keyNumber === 0) {
    $keyNumber = count($array);
  }
  return $array[$keysArray[$keyNumber - 1]];
}
var_dump(previous("second", $array));
```

Note that if you provide first key then it will return the last value, like a cyclic array. You can handle it however you like.

With a bit tweak, you can also generalize it to return next values.

As for why `prev` isnt working is because it isnt used for that purpose. It just sets the internal pointer of the array to one behind, exact inverse of `next`

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution for taking previous and next items, even if we are at the ends of the array.

```
<?php

$current_key; // the key of the item we want to search from

if (isset($array[$current_key+1])) 
{
  // get the next item if there is 
  $array_next = $array[$current_key+1];
} 
else 
{       
   // if not take the first (this means this is the end of the array)
  $array_next = $array[0];
}       

if (isset($array[$current_key-1])) 
{
   // get the previous item if there is
   $array_prev = $array[$current_key-1]; 
} 
else 
{   
  // if not take the last item (this means this is the beginning of the array)
  $array_prev = $array[count($array)-1];        
}
```

Comment: It will work only if the index is numerical and sequential(Ascending order).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding further on the solution of Luca Borrione and cenk, so that you can wrap around the end of the array in either direction, you may use:

```
function getAdjascentKey($key, $hash = array(), $increment) {
    $keys = array_keys($hash);    
    $found_index = array_search($key, $keys);
    if ($found_index === min(array_keys($keys)) && $increment === -1) {
        $found_index = max(array_keys($keys))+1;
    }
    if ($found_index === max(array_keys($keys)) && $increment === +1) {
        $found_index = min(array_keys($keys))-1;
    }       
    return $keys[$found_index+$increment];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner solution that accepts any type of keys and you can implement in a function or use as is:

```php
$previousKey =
    array_keys($yourArray)[
        array_search(
            $currentKey,
            array_keys($yourArray)
        ) - 1
    ]
    ??
    null;
```

For example:

```php
$yourArray = [
    30 => ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    'keyA' => ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC'],
    8848 => ['valueX', 'valueY', 'valueZ']
];

echo
    array_keys($yourArray)[
        array_search(
                'keyA',
                array_keys($yourArray)
        ) - 1
    ]
    ??
    null;
```

Would echo `30`

Here it is in the form of a function:

```php
/**
 * Given an array and a key, returns the key that precedes it.
 * Works with hash arrays with any type of keys.
 * @param array $array The array to search the previous key in
 * @param mixed $pointerKey The key in the array that follows the key to be returned
 * @return mixed The key that precedes the specified $pointerKey in the $array, or null if the $pointerKey was not found or was the first key.
 */
function getPreviousKey(
    array $array,
    mixed $pointerKey
): mixed {
    return
        array_keys($array)[
            array_search(
                $pointerKey,
                array_keys($array)
            ) - 1
        ]
        ??
        null;
}
```

Please note:

- This code will return `null` if the specified key was not found, or it was the first key on the array.
- Since it makes use of PHP's null coalescing operator `??`, this code needs PHP version >= 7.