# Get value of previous array key

Tags: php, arrays

So I tried doing this :

```
$array = array('first'=>'111', 'second'=>'222', 'third'=>'333');

var_dump(prev($array["second"]));
```

Hoping to get `111` but I get `NULL`. Why?

`$array["second"]` returns `222`. Shouldn't we get `111` when we use PHP's `prev()` function?

How to get the previous value of an array if it exists using the key?

Comment: From the manual - `prev — Rewind the internal array pointer` If you are not looping over the array then the internal array pointer will be the first occurance in the array

Comment: Why don't you just skip out on the key so that the key is the index? e.g. 0, 1, 2 - then if you get the array element as $key => $value you can just subtract the $key by 1 e.g. $array[$key-1]

Comment: There is already an answer to this. Please check the existed one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792673/php-get-previous-array-element-knowing-current-array-key).

Comment: @dpap flag it as dupe^^ :)

Comment: @dpap definitely a dup, sorry I haven't found that answer. I accepted your dup request.

Comment: @Equgonyka it's ok mate. It is possible not to find what you are looking for. That's why I mentioned it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current value from `$array["second"]` is not an array and [prev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) takes an array as a parameter.

You have to move the internal pointer of the `$array` and then get the previous value.

```
$array = array('first'=>'111', 'second'=>'222', 'third'=>'333');
while (key($array) !== "second") next($array);
var_dump(prev($array));
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`prev` function expects an array as an argument but you're passing a string.

`$array["second"]` evaluates to `'222'`

Comment: Oh, that's why it's not working! Thanks for the info. How to get then the previous value using the key of the current one?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you point directly the previous value, without iterating the array.

```
$array = array('first'=>'111', 'second'=>'222', 'third'=>'333');
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
$values = array_values($array);
var_dump($values[$keys['second']-1]);
```