# PHP: Start while loop at specific rows on SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm just wondering how I could fetch data using a while loop at row 5 in my SQL table and end it at row 8.

Here is an example of my current code:

```
while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                        echo '
                        <li>Mileage: '.number_format($row["Mileage"]).'</li>
                        <li>Engine size: '.$row["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
                        ';} ?>
```

So as you can see I'd like to make it so the while loop only loops from row 5 to row 8 so I'd be left with 4 li's with the unique data in those columns. As it stands it is currently looping every row in the SQL table which is what I don't want.

Any code examples would be great as I am really stuck on this at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: The answer from Sujit is most likely what you want but an answer to the literal question (start looping an array at a specific index): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795625/how-to-set-an-arrays-internal-pointer-to-a-specific-position-php-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL developers and SQL designers must have actually been able to predict this question years back. :)

`LIMIT` clause comes to your rescue

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx