# PHP return next and previous array items

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following simple array and php

```
$my_array=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"purple","e"=>"yellow");


$match_key = array_search("blue",$my_array);
                echo $match_key;
```

I would like to create two variables that are the array item either side of $match_key.  So in the example above I am trying to end up with...

```
$previous = 'green';
$next = 'purple';
```

What is the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no way of changing your array structure, you could do the following by "creating" a new array with **just** the values of the original array, via [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values)

```
$vals = array_values($my_array);
$match_key = array_search("blue", $vals);

echo "PREV: ". $vals [($match_key - 1)] . "\n";
echo "CURR: ". $vals[$match_key] ."\n";
echo "NEXT: ". $vals [($match_key + 1)] . "\n";
```

Which returns:

```
PREV: green
CURR: blue
NEXT: purple
```

Now you'll need to do key handling/etc to ensure the code doesn't throw any errors and handles your keys in a subtle way.

---

There are various other ways ([*inspired by this post*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/795636/2518525)) that harnesses in-built functions, although seemingly taking longer to process:

```
$match_key = array_search("blue", $my_array);
// loop through and set the array pointer to the $match_key element
while (key($my_array) !== $match_key) next($my_array);

$current = $my_array[$match_key];
$prev = prev($my_array);
next($my_array); // set the array pointer to the next elem (as we went back 1 via prev())
$next = next($my_array);
```

Which returns the previous, current & next as below:

```
CURRENT:  blue
PREVIOUS: green 
NEXT:     purple
```

Comment: I'd suggest using min and max for limiting the next and previous keys, and array_values to ensure the array is always 0 indexed.

Comment: @Rob Agreed, although I've left the answer to the scope of the question. We'll see what he OP comes back with

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_values()` is the way to go.  This creates a new indexed array in the same order as your original array.

Then you can search that for your value using `array_search()` which returns the numeric index.  Then just +1 for the next and -1 for the previous.

Of course you may want to verify that the value you are searching for actually exists.  If so, then ensure `index+1` and `index-1` also exist and set as `null` if they don't.

Something like this:

```
$my_val = 'blue';

$int_indexes = array_values($my_array); // store all values into integer indexed array

if ($index = array_search($my_val, $int_indexes)) { // don't set prev-next if value not found
    $prev = array_key_exists($index - 1, $int_indexes) ? $int_indexes[$index - 1] : null;
    $next = array_key_exists($index + 1, $int_indexes) ? $int_indexes[$index + 1] : null;
}

echo "previous: $prev" . '<br>';
echo "this: $my_val" . '<br>';
echo "next: $next";
```

Gives you results:

```
//    previous:  green
//    this:      blue
//    next:      purple
```

And if your searched value is at the beginning or end, no worries, you just get a `null` value.  And it your searched value isn't found, no worries, you just get 2 `null` values.